# Payment with stripe in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

i am working on the payment transfer using stripe but i have received this error which is not able to solve.

The error which i am receiving is:

> Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 400) (Request req_98Vxx1rihtv4Gi) Insufficient funds in Stripe account. In test mode, you can add funds to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance) by creating a charge with 4000 0000 0000 0077 as the card number.  You can use the the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance).

This is my controller code:

```
@offer_transaction = OfferTransaction.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@offer_transaction.offer_accepted_by)
    if @user.role_id == 2
      if @user.stripe_connect_account_id.present?
        puts @offer_transaction.id
          @pay = Stripe::Transfer.create({
            amount: (@offer_transaction.amount).floor,
            currency: 'usd',
            destination: @offer_transaction.transfer_payment_in,
            description: 'Transfer for test@example.com'},
            {:stripe_account => @user.stripe_connect_account_id})
```

Comment: what happened when you followed the advice in the error message? (ie added funds to the available balance using the CC card given as an example) ?

Comment: yes i have already added amount using the cc card given in the example.given total amout:$688,553

Comment: Good. That was not clear from your description. So can you show us the results from using the  /v1/balance endpoint ?

Comment: i haven't use v1/balance endpoint because i dont know how to work with that. If i am creating a charge then its successfully getting created at every time but when i am creating transfer it shows the error that insufficient  fund in the account.and also want to inform that its shows some warning like "$668,953.71 USD is on hold!
Please add a USD denominated account in order to resume USD transfers."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342861/money-transfer-to-bank-account-with-stripe

Comment: "i haven't use v1/balance endpoint because i dont know how to work with that" then the first thing I'd recommend is following the instructions given to you in the error message ie: "(for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance)"